# how do I resolve this type of line integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vectors, vector-analysis

$r(t) = (2t\sqrt 3,1+2sin(t),2cos(t))$  with  $t\in[0,2\pi]$

I need to solve : $\int_rxyz ds$

also I need to know how to resolve this type :

$\int_r F dr$

knowing that $F(x,y) = ({y\over1+xy},{x\over1+xy})$ and $r(t) = (cos(t),2sin(t))$  with  $t\in[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a scalar function then:

$$\int_C f \ ds = \int_{a}^b f(r) \|r'\| \ dt$$

If $F$ is a vector field we have:

$$\int_{C} F \cdot d\textbf{r} = \int_{a}^b F(\gamma) \cdot \gamma' \ dt$$

Comment: Could  you also help me calculate those examples with the r(t) values that I wrote please ? i know how to calculate ||r|| but a and b is 0 and 2 pi ?

Comment: All you have to do is plug the values in. In the first example $f = xyz$, so what is $f(r)$=?

Comment: yes I know :D , but a and b is 0 and 2 pi ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks , and what about the second one $F(\gamma)$ ? your $\gamma$ simbol is equivalent to my $r$ ?

Comment: The bounds are the same again. You have $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: but what is $F(\gamma)$ and $\gamma'$ .your $\gamma$ simbol is equivalent to my $r$ ?

Comment: Yes. $\gamma$ is just a parametrization of your closed curve, as $r$ was.